# PHP UTF8 preg_match output different on live server

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match, utf

When using `preg_match('/^[\w-]+$/u', $value)` my development server (`5.3.15`) returns true for umlaut words. My live server (`5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19`) returns false.

What do I have to do to make the live server behave the same way as my development server? (Unfortunately, I cannot simply update the php version.)

The code is exactly the same on both machines. Both serve pages as UTF8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` is defined to be `[A-Za-z0-9_]` iirc.

try `preg_match('/^[\pL-]+$/u', $value)` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: I ended up using something `preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}-]+$/u', $value)`